# Finding particular product exist in firebase or not

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

[image]

Hello
I am working with react+firebase.

Can you please tell me.. how to find the whether particular item exist in Firebase or not.

Like as in given image

how to find particular product exist where productId is "-KY5gzllzbAl1jAACcP"

name of particular table is "productcoredetails".

```
      var query = firebase.database().ref('ProductCoreDetails');
    query.once("value", function(snapshot) {

        console.log('value of snapshot is', snapshot.val().ProductId);
        if(snapshot.hasChild(ProductId)){
            console.log('PRODUCT EXIST');
        }
        else{
            console.log('Product doesnt exist');
        }

    });
```

Tried many solution but nothing works for me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.DataSnapshot#exists):

```
firebase.database().ref('ProductCoreDetails').child(YourProductId).once("value", function(snapshot) {
        if(snapshot.exists()){
            console.log('PRODUCT EXIST');
        }
        else{
            console.log('Product doesnt exist');
        }
})
```

You can also use the Promise based way (like the example in the docs):

```
firebase.database().ref('ProductCoreDetails').child(YourProductId).once("value")
.then(function(snapshot) {
        if(snapshot.exists()){
            console.log('PRODUCT EXIST');
        }
        else{
            console.log('Product doesnt exist');
        }
})
.catch(function(error){console.log('cant retrieve product', error)})
```